# Encoding problem downloading HTML using mechanize and Python 2.6

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, mechanize

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
page = browser.open(url)
html = page.get_data()

print html
```

It shows some strange characters. I suppose that it is UTF-8 string but Python doesn't know that and cannot show it properly.

How can I convert this string to unicode string like

```
u = u'test'
```

Comment: Tell us the URL or some of the strange characters that appear on the page. As of your `UnicodeDecodeError`, the document is definitely not correct UTF-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was gzipped

```
def ungzipResponse(r,b):
    headers = r.info()
    if headers['Content-Encoding']=='gzip':
        import gzip
        gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=r, mode='rb')
        html = gz.read()
        gz.close()
        headers["Content-type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
        r.set_data( html )
        b.set_response(r)

response = browser.open(url)
ungzipResponse(response, browser)
html = response.read()
```

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, you should really use an existing library that handles low-level stuff like this for you.

Comment: I've tried to find how to make it easier but it seems like the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
u = html.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: unexpected code byte

Comment: Then it isn't utf-8.  You should examine the headers to see what character set is being returned.

Comment: facebook.com, Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: @how: Save the output to a file and open it in a UTF-aware editor or use a hex editor to see whether it's really UTF-8 what mechanize returns.

Comment: Sorry, it was gzipped. Forgot to ungzip :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to define the encoding
like :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
```

mechanize need it .

for more information check this out 
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: but you need : # -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
not # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- –