# python inconsistent behaviour reading content from EU web page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to extract content from the following EU page:

http://europa.eu/about-eu/countries/member-countries/greece/index_el.htm

and tried opening the page with urllib2 and mechanize, but I get some garbled, strangely encoded text.

```
url='http://europa.eu/about-eu/countries/member-countries/greece/index_el.htm'

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
cookies = mechanize.CookieJar()
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US)     AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.41 Safari/534.7')]

a=browser.open(url,timeout=5)
content=a.read()
```

gives

```
>>> content[:100]
'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xbcW\xddo\x1b\xc7\x11\x7fv\xfe\x8a\xf5\x050\x12\xc0\xe4I\xfejkS\x0c\\\x89M\x8c\xfa\xab\xb2\x84\xa2\x08\x0cay\xb7<\xae\xb9\xb7{\xbe\xdb\xa3\xcc\x16\x05$\xcb\xae\xeb\xc0\x0eP\xa4F\x9f\x8a6\xe8\xabcWQTWV\\\xbd\xc4\xafG\xf9?\xea\xcc\xdd\xf1x\xa4HK:\xc9\\A\xe4r?'
```

but sometimes it works:

```
>>> content[:100]
'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'
```

so what can I do to avoid running into this problem?

Comment: Some responses are gzipped, I suspect. Check the `transfer-encoding` header.

Comment: How to check the header?

Comment: and if yes, look [here](http://mattshaw.org/news/python-mechanize-gzip-response-handling/), same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3805241/1265154)

Comment: I get the KeyError: 'content-encoding' error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving gzipped content; test for the Content-Encoding header and decompress:

```
import zlib

if a.info().get('Content-Encoding', '').lower() == 'gzip':
    decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    content = decompressor.decompress(content)
```

Alternatively, use the excellent [`python-requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) which will handle sessions for you, but also will transparently decompress gzip and deflate responses for you.

Comment: these are the keys I have:
a=r.info()
a.keys()
['content-length', 'via', 'content-language', 'x-cache', 'accept-ranges', 'server', 'last-modified', 'connection', 'etag', 'date', 'content-type', 'age']

Comment: @hmghaly: are you certain that that is the zipped response?

Comment: @hmghaly: the URL you used in your question certainly gives *me* a `Content-Encoding: gzip` response.

Comment: @MartijnPieters me too.

Comment: maybe that's the catch, because sometimes it works normally and sometimes it gives this strange (probabbly gzipped) output, maybe when you ran it you got this header, will try again

Comment: @hmghaly: It could be that that server uses a farm of caching servers, some of which gzip, some of which do not.

Comment: and yes, I also captured the response with gzip, so you are absolutely correct, thank you :)